Focus External Display When Moving Mouse
I have an external monitor attached to my MacBook.
When my mouse crosses from my MacBook into the external display, I often run a keyboard shortcut to close a tab on the external display. The problem is that this ends up closing the tab on my MacBook.
So now I have to explicitly click on the window in my external display, and only then run the keyboard shortcut. This additional click is annoying.
How do I make it so that a given display is "focused" when my mouse has crossed into it?
